# How do I unassign variables in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I've written:

```
d: 3
```

How do I then unassign this, if I want to delete this variable?

I tried `delete d` and `_d` but neither of these worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete a variable from the root namespace you can use:

```
delete d from `.
```

More information can be found here:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/delete/